# How to resolve NullPointerException in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am developing a web application using jsp and servlet and I want to show all my records from my database and the number of records in a table.

I have created a DAO in which I performed queries where they returned the data correctly and put it in a session in a servlet giving the name of  `sessaoListaMotoristasTodos` and `totalMotorista`.

But when passing the values ​​retrieved from the session and assigning the variables, the values ​​are not assigned, the called variables are  `List ListMotoristas`  and `Integer totalRegistros` giving a **java.lang.NullPointerException**

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
    MotoristasDAO dao= new MotoristasDAO();
    MotoristasDAO dao2= new MotoristasDAO();
    String pesquisa=request.getParameter("pesquisa");
    try {
        if(pesquisa==null){
            pesquisa="";
        } 
   Integer totalMotorista=dao.totalRegistros(pesquisa);
   request.setAttribute("totalMotoristas", totalMotorista);
   List listaMotoristas2=dao2.mostrarMotoristas();
   request.setAttribute("sessaoListaMotoristasTodos", listaMotoristas2);
   RequestDispatcher rd= request.getRequestDispatcher("/listaMotoristas2.jsp");
   rd.forward(request, response);
   } catch (Exception e) {
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro na servelet"+e);
   }
}
```

JSP:

```
<%
List listaMotoristas=(List) request.getAttribute("sessaoListaMotoristasTodos");
Integer totalRegistros= (Integer) request.getAttribute("totalMotorista");
int totalPaginas=totalRegistros/limite;
if(totalRegistros%limite!=0){
    totalPaginas++;
}else{
    totalPaginas=0;
}
%>
```

Comment: In this line of code  request.setAttribute("sessaoListaMotoristasTodos", dao2); you are setting dao2 as value but while retrieving it in jsp  as request.getAttribute("sessaoListaMotoristasTodos"); It wont return you a list. It will return dao2, from this u need to get the list or else the other option is set the list as follows request.setAttribute("sessaoListaMotoristasTodos", listaMotoristas2); and in jsp you can retrieve the list as you are doing

Comment: Also you are not setting the variables in session scope , you are setting them in request scope. But in your question you say you are setting the variables in session scope , which is wrong

Comment: Avinash Readdy when I hedge the request scope in the variable the variable does not receive the value it gets null

Comment: Just check whether List listaMotoristas2=dao2.mostrarMotoristas(); is returning data or an empty list or null.

Answer (score 0):

```
 MotoristasDAO dao2= new MotoristasDAO();
 List listaMotoristas2=dao2.mostrarMotoristas();
```

As per your code you are doing this

```
request.setAttribute("sessaoListaMotoristasTodos", dao2);
```

But you should do this

```
request.setAttribute("sessaoListaMotoristasTodos", listaMotoristas2);
```

or this

```
request.setAttribute("sessaoListaMotoristasTodos", dao2.mostrarMotoristas());
```

you should set the list **"listaMotoristas2"** in the request and not the **"dao2"**

and now in the jsp your code is as follows

```
List listaMotoristas=(List) request.getAttribute("sessaoListaMotoristasTodos");
```

This will not return a list it will return dao2

Comment: I made the changes as you recommended but continued the same error

Comment: when I setting the request scope in the variable, the variable does not receive the value it gets null